# How to embed a Google Docs Video in my website

Tags: google-drive, video, embed

The UI does not have an "embed" button.

I managed to make it work copying the HTML from the Docs site (using Firebug and Developer Tools, because the HTML is injected via JavaScript).

But it seems that the vars are timestamped because the video stops working some minutes later.

Is there a way to embed them or must wait for Google to support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Docs UI has changed again.

If you want to embed a Google Docs video on any website (not just a Google sites err… site), now you need to click 'File' then choose 'embed'.

*But*, be aware that only those with permissions to see the video will be able to play it.

In other words, if you've set it to private then most people won't be able to play it.

Answer (score 1):

While on your Google site, go to the Insert menu and select `Video > Google Docs Video`. From there, choose from the videos that are in your documents list and click Select to insert the video into your Google site.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - I missed the Docs part.

It appears that this is not supported at present - there has been a lot of requests for it in the forums so I have no doubt that it will get implemented.

The only thing I can think of as a workaround would be to share the video and provide the link on you site or use an iframe on your site that points to the shared link.

I will leave this content here for others as it may be useful.

**Note: The following does not apply to Google Docs Video - only Google Video**

You should be able to use the `Embed Video` link.

Note: Google are no longer offering the ability upload to Google Video

> **How do I put a video on my site?**
>
> To embed a video on websites or blogs,
>   refer to the instructions below. The
>   embed code is only available on
>   certain videos that were uploaded to
>   Google Video.
>
> 1. Visit Google Video and find the video you want.
> 2. Click on the "Embed video" link on the right-hand side of the playback
>      page.
> 3. Copy and paste the HTML code to your webpage.
> 4. If you'd like your embedded video to begin playing automatically, go to
>      the end of the embed code and add
>      FlashVars="autoPlay=true".
>
> If the HTML code doesn't appear and
>   you've uploaded the video, you may
>   need to change your video's settings.
>
> Here's how:
>
> 1. Sign in at https://upload.video.google.com.
> 2. Click "Edit Video Info >>" beside your video in the "Video Information"
>      column.
> 3. Click "Advanced Options."
> 4. Select "Allow users to place this video on their own websites" next to
>      "Embedded video."
> 5. Click "Save Video Information."

[Taken from this Google FAQ article](http://video.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35093)

Comment: I was talking about Google **Docs** video http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2011/01/this-week-in-docs-video-player-in.html

Comment: @Eduardo - I have updated my answer, thanks